# Is has_many => :through a violation of the Law of Demeter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, law-of-demeter

If it is, what's its defence? And if it isn't, why isn't it?

Comment: IMO the defense, if any is really needed, is that it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is declaring new neighbor, akin to delegation.  OTOH, if it were possible, it might be getting a bit bad to do multiple :through levels...  (Do I remember correctly that they made this possible lately?)